# Chrome extension to automatically click a button every 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to build a Chrome extension which automatically click a button every 3 seconds.

This is my manifest.json file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Clicker",
    "description": "My Clicker",
    "version": "1.0",

    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["background.js", "arrive.min.js"]
        }
    ],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "favicon.ico",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs"]
}
```

This is my background.js file:

```js
function myFunc() {
 document.getElementById('hello').click();
};

setInterval(myFunc, 3000);
```

And this is the page I'm using to try it:

```html
<button id="hello" onclick="javascript:alert('hello')">Ciao a tutti</button>
```

Unfortunately, Chrome gives me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Why this isn't working?

Comment: is your background.js function being called before the button is in the DOM

Comment: I don't think background scripts can interact with the DOM. You'll need to use a content script for this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: @Sidney what is the difference between content_scripts and scripts?

Comment: @Surreal I don't know

Comment: Background scripts are  executed in a different environment then the web pages for security reasons, which is why you need to specify permissions / settings in the manifest. To interact with a page's dom you need to use content scripts

Comment: You should read through the documentation if you haven't already https://developer.chrome.com/extensions

Comment: OK, I edited the manifest file. Now it looks like this: {
 "manifest_version": 2,

 "name": "Clicker",
 "description": "My Clicker",
 "version": "1.0",
 
 "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["background.js", "arrive.min.js"]
  }
 ],

 "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "favicon.ico",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
 },
 "permissions": [
  "activeTab"
 ]
}

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't work anyway!!

Comment: @Sidney Background scripts _can_ access the dom through the tabs api with the correct permissions. But for more common simple cases, content scripts are a better, more secure option. Your content script runs as a privately scoped module sharing the full dom of the page it runs on. You can use message passing through the background script if you need to interact with other tabs.

Comment: @skylize I updated the manifest (now I'm using content script), but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

You may be trying to access the element before it exists in the dom. I'm sure that something like `onload` would help with this, but since modern 3rd party websites are constantly redrawing the dom, you never know if the element will be ready when you go looking for it. I like to set up some helpers to poll for the desired element for a specified amount of time. These 2 files below are a complete working extension to automatically click your first `favorite tag` when you visit `stackoverflow.com` homepage.

Edit: When I first posted this I included "https://stackoverflow.com/questions" in the matches, but I removed it because it makes it too hard to access questions not tagged with a favorite tag.

---

*manifest.json*

```
{
  "name": "my-favorite",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Click favorite tag",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com/skylize",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://stackoverflow.com/"
      ],
      "js": ["favorite.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

*favorite.js*

```
// Helper to promisify waiting with setTimeout
//
function delay (time, ...args){
  return new Promise( resolve=>
    // |0 is just an explicit coercion to int
    setTimeout(()=>resolve(...args), time|0))
}

// Helper to promisify throwing after timeout
//
function timeout (delay, errMsg){
  return new Promise( (r, reject)=> {
    setTimeout( ()=>{
      reject( new Error(errMsg || 'Timed out') )
    }, delay|0)
  })
}

function getElementWhenItExists(selector){
  // flag to end recursive search if timed out
  //
  let keepSearching = true

  // recursively search for element every 100ms
  //
  async function search (){
    const node = document.querySelector(selector)
    if ( !node && keepSearching)
      return await delay(100).then(search)
    return node
  }

  // race search against timeout and return promise with
  //  found node or a timeout error
  //
  return Promise.race([
    search(),
    timeout(10000, `Timed out looking for ${selector}`)
      .catch(e=> {
        keepSearching = false
        throw e
      })
  ])
}

const link = getElementWhenItExists('#interestingTags a')

link.then(a => a.click())
```

Comment: I kind of like this functionality. I think I will leave this extension installed. Hahaha.

Comment: it works :) I tried editing the manifest like this "matches": [ "https://stackoverflow.com/*"]. Now it keeps clicking the element. How to make it stop clicking once it finds the element?

Comment: That's quite a bit more complicated. One possibility is store a boolean in chrome.storage. Check the boolean before you click, and set it after you click. Then send message to background.js instructing it to watch current tab, and whenever tab is no longer on stackoverflow, reset the stored boolean and quit watching. Or maybe watch all tabs and don't reset boolean until all tabs are no longer on stackoverflow. (You can access current tab href from content script, but it won't help because when href changes, window gets reloaded and your script gets nuked.)

Comment: Isn't there an easier method?

Comment: I found this https://swizec.com/blog/how-to-properly-wait-for-dom-elements-to-show-up-in-modern-browsers/swizec/6663. I tried it but it shows me the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token try

Comment: Another idea: what about checking if the link has the class "clicked_by_extension" and adding that class to the clicked links by the extension?

Comment: Not sure exactly what's up with your `requestAnimationFrame`, but persoally I think that's not a great strategy for an Extension anyway. That trick relies on you being certain an element is getting queued for render, whereas when mutating someone else's page, you can't be sure they have even decided to render that element at all.

Comment: Changing the outbound link like that would work in the small case of not clicking again on the very next page, but it will still click if you opened another question from that page. Or if you found a stackoverflow question on google and clicked it, instead of seeing the answer, you get redirected to your favorite tag. ☹ (also, you would want to append a url query string, rather than setting a class on the link element)